# fragment replace transaction not remembering state of variable bitmap

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an asyncTask to get an image (it has dynamic width and height so not using picasso or fresco).  i am using url.OpenConnection for this but i would like to cache the results so the next call with the same url would simply check a cache and return the results.  how can i set it to use caching?

```
 private var mBitmap: Bitmap? = null

private inner class FetchImageAsync : AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String): Bitmap? {
            // your background code fetch InputStream
            val imageId = params[0]
            var bmp: Bitmap? = null
            try {
                val url = URL("https://" + BASE_ENDPOINT + "/" + imageId)
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream())
                mBitmap = bmp
            } catch (e: Exception) {
            }
            return bmp
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(bmp: Bitmap?) {
            super.onPostExecute(bmp)
            if (bmp != null && activity != null) {
                iv.setImageBitmap(bmp)

            }
        }
    }
```

i tried saving the results of the decoded bitmap into a class variable called mBitmap but when the fragment is "replaced" and i return to the fragment it mBitmap is null again ?  why ?  i thought state would be remember on fragment replace.  To be clear i am looking for a way to not keep doing the network call on teh same url after i have already done it. this should be all local , not from server end.

here is how i am replacing the fragment:

```
 public void replaceFragment(Fragment f) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.replace(R.id.fl_attributes_container, f, f.getClass().getName()).commit();
    }


  <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fl_attributes_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

UPDATE: HERE IS my entire fragment:

```
 class MyFragment : Fragment() {


private var mBitmap: Bitmap? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false)
        return rootView
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initView()
    }


    private fun initView() {
        setupImage()  
    }


    private fun setupImage() {

            //the mBitmap is always null after i come back to the fragment from a replace, why ?
                mBitmap?.let { bitmap -> iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap) }
                        ?: run { FetchImageAsync().execute(it) }
            }




    private inner class FetchImageAsync : AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String): Bitmap? {
            // your background code fetch InputStream
            val imageId = params[0]
            var bmp: Bitmap? = null
            try {
                val url = URL("https://" + BASE_ENDPOINT + "/" + imageId)
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream())
                mBitmap = bmp
            } catch (e: Exception) {
            }
            return bmp
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(bmp: Bitmap?) {
            super.onPostExecute(bmp)
            if (bmp != null && activity != null) {
                iv.setImageBitmap(bmp)
            }
        }
    }



    companion object {
        fun newInstance(b: Bundle?): MyFragment {
            val frag = MyFragment()
            frag.arguments = b ?: Bundle()
            return frag
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please show how your replaceFragment is used?

Comment: if you do a replace fragment the UI is destroyed but the state of the object should be preserved. right ? just the view part of the fragment gets destroyed. so just onDestroyView is called but not onDestroy. i've incuded the replace fragment for you to see.

Comment: Yes, but which parameter are you passing to replaceFragment(...) ?

Comment: i updated my answer with the entire fragment being passed in. its passed in by calling  replaceFragment(MyFragment.Companion.newInstance(null));

Comment: "I return to my fragment" - do you mean you press "Back"?

Comment: no. i actually call replace again to go back to it. i have multiple fragments.  each time i want to transition to the next one i DO NOT use back button. i call replace to  go to the previous one.  does this saved state thing only work with back button ?  the thing is my fragments are small little ones inside of a bigger fragment that hosts them .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174587/discussion-between-user8035311-and-j2emanue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using your `replaceFragment` method to switch back to some previous `Fragment`.  As stated in the comment it's done as follows:

```
replaceFragment(MyFragment.Companion.newInstance(null));
```

This, however, takes a new instance parameter each time so your replacing `Fragment` is a brand new object that can't know about member variables from another `Fragment`.

To address this try to tag your `Fragment` so that it could be reused if found. So, right before calling replaceFragment do something like:

```
var frag = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag)
if (frag == null) {
    frag = MyFragment.Companion.newInstance(null)     
} 
replaceFragment(frag)
```